# Filtering firebase data and ordering results

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing an HTML/JavaScript app that uses Firebase as the database.

My data is structured somewhat like this:

```
steps/
- GUID
-- tripId
-- name
-- description
-- order
-- launchDate
```

I want to select any items from steps whose *tripId* matches a specific value (passed in a variable).   I then want to order the results by descending *order*.

I am more use to T-SQL type syntax so am getting confused in the world of realtime databases.

Here is a snippet of what my code looks like now.

```
var steps = function readSteps(format, tripId) {
    var stepsRef;
    stepsRef = firebase.database().ref('steps/');
    stepsRef.orderByChild('order').on('value', function (response) {
        // DO SOME LOGIC HERE WITH 'response' DATA
    });
}
```

I don't know how to filter these results and I don't see how to easily do a descending sort.  *order* is an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting all steps for order 42, you'd query with:

```
stepsRef = firebase.database().ref('steps/');
stepsRef.orderByChild('order').equalTo(42).on('value', function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(stepSnapshot) {
        console.log(stepSnapshot.key, stepSnapshot.val());
    });
});
```

But if you're always going to be looking up the steps for an order, you're better off modeling the JSON differently:

```
orderSteps
  order42
    step1: ...
    step2: ...
    step3: ...
  order43
    step1: ...
    step2: ...
```

This allows you to retrieve the steps for an order, without needing a query:

```
stepsRef = firebase.database().ref('orderSteps/order42');
stepsRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(stepSnapshot) {
        console.log(stepSnapshot.key, stepSnapshot.val());
    });
});
```

If you *also* want to order this result on a child property, it'd become:

```
stepsRef.orderByChild("field").on('value', function (snapshot) {
```

I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and viewing [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) to learn more about modeling data in a NoSQL database.

Comment: I just realized my example may have been a bit confusing.  order is a pre-specified sort order that I want to sort by.   I am trying to match on tripId.   Since the orderBy seems to dictate the "field" I am looking at for equalTo, how do I do a sort and a query.

Comment: I added a snippet for how to order on a property in the second JSON structure. The first JSON structure won't allow that, since a Firebase Database query can only contain one `orderBy` clause. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase